# How to judge if a @PathVariable exists in request URL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api-gateway

I am trying to write an api permission filter on gateway. Tokens that do not carry with the specific roles should be prohibited from accessing resources. All the requests have been filtered effectively, except for apis that contains `@PathVariable` params. For example, an api with the URI `/api/v1/query/{id}`, the param `id` might be a `uuid` in some cases, and may be a `long` value in other cases.
Are there any better ways except adding more and more Regex patterns? The overall goal of gateway is to consume as less time as possible.

Comment: You can supply your own `Converter` to `FormatterRegistry`. Check this out: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder

Comment: @PranjalGore That does not work in my situation as the code I am writing will run on the API Gateway, and the filtered Api list are not located in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a proper solution anyway. The `@PathVariable` in all the projects are located in the last or the last two parts in the URL. e.g. `/api/v1/data/query/{uid}/{pid}` or something like that. So we could eliminate that part using Apache Common's `StringUtils#lastIndexOf()` and `StringUtils#substring()`.

To write the code for demonstration, import both Hutool and Commons-Lang3.

```java
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.hutool/hutool-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
import cn.hutool.core.util.IdUtil;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/data/query/" + IdUtil.simpleUUID() + "/" + IdUtil.getSnowflake(1L, 16).nextId();
        System.out.println(url);
        int index = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(url, "/");
        String subUrl = StringUtils.substring(url, 0, index);
        System.out.println(subUrl);
        int index2 = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(subUrl, "/");
        String subOfSubUrl = StringUtils.substring(url, 0, index2);
        System.out.println(subOfSubUrl);
    }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/data/query/19280769925f43d98b2af405579955ac/1356927788629626880
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/data/query/19280769925f43d98b2af405579955ac
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/data/query
```

By simplifying the uri to the simpliest, in my case is `/api/v1/data/query`, it is easy to write the related codes to check of roles.